# How the variable SML_LIB is defined in SML mlb files?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I want to use a variable called MY_LIB in a similar way as SML_LIB is used. How can I define MY_LIB so it can be used inside a `.mlb` file?

```
ann                                                                                
   "MY_LIB /path/to/my/lib" (* this does not work*)
in
  local 
  $(MY_LIB)/functions.mlb
  $(MY_LIB)/functions2.mlb
  $(MY_LIB)/functions3.mlb
  $(MY_LIB)/functions4.mlb
  $(MY_LIB)/functions5.mlb
 in                                                                               
    main.sml                                                                   
 end 
end
```

Is there any any way to define it inside the `.mlb` file?

Why this doesnt work?

Can `ann` directives be used for this purpose?

How the variable SML_LIB is defined in SML mlb files?

Comment: Have a look at this page: http://mlton.org/MLBasisPathMap

Comment: Thank you `-mlb-path-var` allows me to set VARs in the command line